# Run an app script function if an exact cell contains a value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Im hoping I get some help. Im looking to have a certain cell ("B2") trigger a function ("resetCheckbox") if that cell ("B2") says "Clear". Then following that, clear contents in that cell ("B2"). The current script i have for unchecking boxes works but i need to be able to set up a trigger that will work on an iPhone.

Here is the link to the Google spreadsheet:

[Link to Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HTLhe1U1tyrGGFqRDUHeuxpcHXN_U2VtyhkyonHhWvs/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value == "Clear") {
    resetCheckbox();
  }
}
```